# Eclipse Indigo CDT code completion

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse CDT as IDE to develop my application which uses an external library for which I have access to the header files and libraries.
How can I setup my project properties such that I can get code completion (I have code completion for files which belong to my project, but not to the ones which are part of this external library).
I tried the following approach which unfortunately fails.
Project->Properties->C/C++ general->Path and symbols -> Includes 
In Includes, I added the path to the header files.
Unfortunately, this does not seem to work.

So how can I setup my project such that, if I instanciate an object (from this external library) in my project, I can get code completion and see all available public methods?

thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: Sounds right to me. After adding the new include paths force Eclipse to index the newly added paths. Make sure the `#include`s are in place,  save your files, and give Project-C/C++ Index->Rebuild a shot.

Comment: I can see in the header files of this external source, that several macros are used. Shall I add these macros as well in the configuration ?

Comment: Eclipse's indexer should be able to pick off any defines and chose the correct conditional paths. Drop a suspected define at the top of a file that needs the stuff you think is being left out and see that happens.

Comment: You may want to consider using a newer version of Eclipse than Indigo; as of 2016, there have been 5 newer releases of Eclipse since Indigo. If you still can't get this to work with a recent version of Eclipse, please [file a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) with a code example.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> C++ -> CDT User Setting Entries -> Add`

[image]

Comment: I gave it a try and unfortunately this does not really help in y case. thanks anyway